# ConvergenceWarning problem with python jupyter

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I import Olivetti faces database,
here is the error:

```
/Users/mahrokh/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/neural_network/multilayer_perceptron.py:566:
ConvergenceWarning: Stochastic Optimizer: Maximum iterations (200) reached and the optimization hasn't converged yet.
  % self.max_iter, ConvergenceWarning)
```

Comment: import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

Answer (score 2):

That's not an error, that's fine. You can reset the maximum iteration value to something else. This is probably because whatever the problem you are trying to solve is harder than what an MLP of your architecture can solve in 200 iterations.

You can set `max_iter=400` or some higher value.